# How can I retrieve distinct data by using group by

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have following table and its sample data as follows,

```
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| PhoneCode        | SeqID | Active | Token               | CUSID |
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| e29a5e1c695352b8 | 3898  | I      | JYN8CYRVzaKWL-l_K   | 50002 |
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| e29a5e1c695352b8 | 3900  | I      | JYN8CYRVzaKWL-l_K   | 50002 |
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| 741fb28bc72183e3 | 3899  | I      | RU3ReKEw0yin9LxZWCO | 50002 |
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| 741fb28bc72183e4 | 3901  | A      | RU3ReKEw0yin9LxZWCO | 50002 |
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
```

I need to take distinct `PhoneCode` with latest `SeqID`. So I tried following query.

```
SELECT UD.PHONECODE, UD.SeqID, UD.ACTIVE, UD.Token
FROM   DEVICE UD
WHERE UD.CUSID = '50002' AND UD.ACTIVE = 'I'
GROUP BY PHONECODE
```

But its makes error. How can I retrieve following output?

```
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| PhoneCode        | SeqID | Active | Token               | CUSID |
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| e29a5e1c695352b8 | 3900  | I      | JYN8CYRVzaKWL-l_K   | 50002 |
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| 741fb28bc72183e3 | 3899  | I      | RU3ReKEw0yin9LxZWCO | 50002 |
+------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT` - _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: @jarlh not clear, can u please provide me query to solve this please sir

Comment: Never mind, now I see there are different Active codes as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without `GROUP BY` and without self-joins:

```sql
SELECT PHONECODE,
       SeqID,
       ACTIVE,
       Token
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY phonecode ORDER BY seqid DESC) AS rn
  FROM   device d
  WHERE  cusid = 50002
  AND    active = 'I'
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Or, if you want to use `GROUP BY` then you can also use `KEEP`:

```sql
SELECT PHONECODE,
       MAX(SeqID) AS seqid,
       MAX(ACTIVE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY SeqID) AS active,
       MAX(Token) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY SeqID) AS token
FROM   device
WHERE  cusid = 50002
AND    active = 'I'
GROUP BY phonecode;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE device (PhoneCode, SeqID, Active, Token, CUSID ) AS
SELECT 'e29a5e1c695352b8', 3898, 'I', 'JYN8CYRVzaKWL-l_K',   50002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'e29a5e1c695352b8', 3900, 'I', 'JYN8CYRVzaKWL-l_K',   50002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '741fb28bc72183e3', 3899, 'I', 'RU3ReKEw0yin9LxZWCO', 50002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '741fb28bc72183e4', 3901, 'A', 'RU3ReKEw0yin9LxZWCO', 50002 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | PHONECODE | SEQID | ACTIVE | TOKEN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 741fb28bc72183e3 | 3899 | I | RU3ReKEw0yin9LxZWCO |
> | e29a5e1c695352b8 | 3900 | I | JYN8CYRVzaKWL-l_K |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5da81c819c71f1f484c7b4cb632d3bfc)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX()` and a join:

```
SELECT UD.PHONECODE, UD.ACTIVE, UD.Token, UD.SeqID
FROM   DEVICE UD
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PHONECODE, MAX(SeqID) as SEQID
    FROM DEVICE   
    WHERE CUSID = '50002' AND ACTIVE = 'I'
    GROUP BY PHONECODE
 ) T2 ON UD.PHONECODE = T2.PHONECODE AND UD.SEQID = T2.SEQID
```

Comment: If there can be duplicate rows with the same `PhoneCode` and `SeqID` (either with different `ACTIVE` or `CUSID` values) then this may return unexpected results as the filter is only on the `T2` subquery and not also on `UD`.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple sub query

```
SELECT UD.PHONECODE, UD.SeqID, UD.ACTIVE, UD.Token 
FROM device ud
WHERE (UD.PHONECODE, UD.SeqID) IN (
  SELECT PHONECODE, MAX(SeqID) 
  FROM device
  WHERE CUSID = '50002' AND ACTIVE = 'I'
  GROUP BY PHONECODE 
)
```

Comment: This give following error, ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"

Comment: If there can be duplicate rows with the same `PhoneCode` and `SeqID` (either with different `ACTIVE` or `CUSID` values) then this may return unexpected results as the filter is only on the `T2` subquery and not also on `UD`.

Comment: @MTO, If that is a possibility those restrictions can be added to the outer query.

Comment: @NTB_BOY, I've tried that same query on an 11c, 18c and 21c and it works on all of them as can be seen in [this dbfiddler|https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f8b592fbaba6de09ea61206132ad35a]

Comment: @chegancasb You had missed a closing bracket on the `IN` clause. I'd edited the answer to fix it but it appears that the OP ran the query before it got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will work :

```
select phonecode,seqid,active,token,cusid
from
(
    select * , row_number() over(partition by phonecode order by seqid desc) as rownum
    from device
    where cusid = 50002 and active = 'I'
) as t1
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: It will not for three reasons: 1) `AS` before a subquery alias is invalid syntax in Oracle; 2) in Oracle, `ROWNUM` is a keyword referring to a pseudo-column; and 3) you use `SELECT *, ...` without using a table name or table alias before the `*`, which is also invalid syntax in Oracle. If you fix all those [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b28297e077bb6a2ec53eacf56cf8a64f) then you get to the answer I've already given.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for the correction @MT0. I had missed to spot the tag 'oracle' in the question. This solution was tested in mysql workbench.

Answer (score 1):

If your database version is `12c+` and displaying the returning value of `ROW_NUMBER()` function doesn't matter, then such a query as an option without a subquery would be

```sql
SELECT d.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PhoneCode ORDER BY SeqID DESC) AS rn
  FROM device d
 WHERE cusid = 50002
   AND active = 'I'
 ORDER BY rn  
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

where all ties(equal values) of `rn` are included in the result set.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4e4ae79e85f35b4fc7eada982d21822e)</kbd>